Angular application Reload multiple times how to prevent it
I have an Electron app with  Angular  when the first time I run the npm start command, it works correctly. However I save changes, the app reloads multiple times. how can i prevent (stop) it
i want when i save changes then app will reload only  one time not multiple time

what does npm start run exactly? ng serve?
